# Protect restrict Solr Admin url from external user using .htaccess or tomcat

Tags: .htaccess, solr, restriction

I have recently installed Solr on server and i want to restrict only local users can access it with `.htaccess`

```
site.com:8983/solr/admin    [ restrict all user]
```

And below is the .htaccess code

```
RewirteRule on
<FilesMatch "127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin">
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny form all
    Allow 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Or is there any method we can protect / restrict  Solr Admin on `site.com:8983/solr/admin` accessing from other users
Only local ip users can use it..

And i tried this one, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<FilesMatch "127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin">` line will never match anything because you've stuck the hostname and port in the regular expression. Try using the `Location` container instead:

```
<Location "/solr/admin">
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Or better yet, `Directory`:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/document/root/solr/admin"> 
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

You'll need to fill in the full path to the solr/admin directory.

Get rid of the `RewirteRule on` line, it doesn't do anything and it's not even spelled right and will cause a 500 error.

However, neither of these directives can be use in an htaccess file. You need to use these in either the server of vhost config. If you *must* use an htaccess file, then create an htaccess file in your solr/admin directory and simply put these directives in it:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow 127.0.0.1
```

Or, in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^/?solr/admin - [L,F]
```

Comment: I have tried both methods, but its not working... I am using with ports..`

site.com:8983 for solr
site.com:8080 for tomcat`

Comment: where to put this htaccess file?

Comment: @RaheelHasan My answer says: *then create an htaccess file in your solr/admin directory and simply put these directives in it:* or *in the htaccess file in your document root:*

Answer (score 0):

Check following links. Hope they will help you.

- [Restrict Solr Admin Access](http://www.findbestopensource.com/article-detail/restrict-solr-admin-access)
- [Solr Security](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity)
- [Securing Solr administrative console](http://drupal.org/node/658466)
- [How to protect Apache Solr admin console](http://www.knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/how-protect-apache-solr-admin-console)